# Regular expression that matches between quotes, containing escaped quotes

Tags: regex, pcre

*This was originally a question I wanted to ask, but while researching the details for the question I found the solution and thought it may be of interest to others.*

In Apache, the full request is in double quotes and any quotes inside are always escaped with a backslash:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [15/Apr/2005:20:35:37 +0200] "GET /\" foo=bat\" HTTP/1.0" 400 299 "-" "-" "-"
```

I'm trying to construct a regex which matches all distinct fields. My current solution always stops on the first quote after the `GET`/`POST` (actually I only need all the values including the size transferred):

```
^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s+[^\s]+\s+[^\s]+\s+\[(\d+)/([A-Za-z]+)/(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\s+\+\d+\]\s+"[^"]+"\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+|-)
```

I guess I'll also provide my solution from my PHP source with comments and better formatting:

```
$sPattern = ';^' .
    # ip address: 1
    '(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)' .
    # ident and user id
    '\s+[^\s]+\s+[^\s]+\s+' .
    # 2 day/3 month/4 year:5 hh:6 mm:7 ss +timezone
    '\[(\d+)/([A-Za-z]+)/(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\s+\+\d+\]' .
    # whitespace
    '\s+' .
    # request uri
    '"[^"]+"' .
    # whitespace
    '\s+' .
    # 8 status code
    '(\d+)' .
    # whitespace
    '\s+' .
    # 9 bytes sent
    '(\d+|-)' .
    # end of regex
    ';';
```

Using this with a simple case where the URL doesn't contain other quotes works fine:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [15/Apr/2005:20:35:37 +0200] "GET /\ foo=bat\ HTTP/1.0" 400 299 "-" "-" "-"
```

Now I'm trying to get support for none, one or more occurrences of `\"` into it, but can't find a solution. Using regexpal.com I've came up with this so far:

```
^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s+[^\s]+\s+[^\s]+\s+\[(\d+)/([A-Za-z]+)/(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\s+\+\d+\]\s+"(.|\\(?="))*"
```

Here's only the changed part:

```
    # request uri
    '"(.|\\(?="))*"' .
```

However, it's too greedy. It eats everything until the last `"`, when it should only eat until the first `"` not preceded by a `\`. I also tried introducing the requirement that there's no `\` before the `"` I want, but it still eats to the end of the string (Note: I had to add extraneous `\` characters to make this work in PHP):

```
    # request uri
    '"(.|\\(?="))*[^\\\\]"' .
```

But then it hit me: ***`?`**: If used immediately after any of the quantifiers *, +, ?, or {}, makes the quantifier non-greedy (matching the minimum number of times)*

```
    # request uri
    '"(.|\\(?="))*?[^\\\\]"' .
```

The full regex:

```
^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s+[^\s]+\s+[^\s]+\s+\[(\d+)/([A-Za-z]+)/(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\s+\+\d+\]\s+"(.|\\(?="))*?[^\\]"\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+|-)
```

**Update 5th May 2009:**

I discovered a small flaw in the regexp due parsing millions of lines: it breaks on lines which contain the backslash character right before the double quote. In other words:

```
...\\"
```

will break the regex. Apache will not log `...\"` but will always escape the backslash to `\\`, so it's safe to assume that when there're two backslash characters before the double quote.

Anyone has an idea how to fix this with the the regex?

Helpful resources: [the JavaScript Regexp documentation at developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Objects:RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions) and [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
"(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*"
```

This regular expression matches a double quote character followed by a sequence of either any character other than `\` and `"` or an escaped sequence `\`*`α`* (where *`α`* can be any character) followed by the final double quote character. The `(?:`*`expr`*`)` syntax is just a non-capturing group.

Comment: Could you please add some more information about your regex for the benefit of all? I barely managed to understand what I wrote ... thanks :)

Comment: (?:A|B) matches A or B. \\. matches a backslash following any character except newline. [^\\"] matches any character except backslash and double quote. Putting it all together does exactly what you want, +1.