# Why non-word chars are not matched in my regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I need to capture string between quote chars (`"`) to change quotes for fancy ones, thus i created substitution, my code:

```
my $pk = qq|IV Baltic Sea NGO Forum "Challenges for Baltic Sea civil society"|;
$pk =~ s/"(\p{Word}+.?+)"/«$1»/g;
say $pk;
```

I meant regex as that:

1. quoting char
2. followed by at least one word char
3. followed by any char
4. until next quoting char (non-greedy capture)

I don't get captured when there is any non-word char between quotes. Why?

I found [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/694356/196241) too, but i'd like to understand, why my regex does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.?+` is not reluctant quantifier. It is in fact a *possessive* `? quantifier`.

You need to use `.+?` instead.

So, try this:

```
$pk =~ s/"(\p{Word}+.+?)"/«$1»/g;
```

or, you can even use `[^"]+` instead of `reluctant quantifier`. It will automatically stop at the first `"` character:

```
$pk =~ s/"(\p{Word}+[^"]+)"/«$1»/g;
```

Comment: I can't memorize is there `.+?` or `.?+` and `.=` or `=.`. I should have to check this over myself, thank you for pointing and offering other way too! Will accept it in short.

Comment: @w.k. You're welcome :) And there is nothing special about `.=` or `=.` You have only 3 types of quantifiers in regex - `*, + and ?`.

Comment: @w.k. By default those quauntifiers are greedy, i.e., they match as much as they can. So, you add a `?` at the end of each of them to make them reluctant. Also, you add a `+` at the end of them to make them `possessive`. With which, the string that they match, will not be backtracked.

Comment: Don't forget `{n,m}`, that's a quantifier, too.

Comment: @TimPietzcker. Ah! Forgot that.

Comment: @Rohit Jain: `.=` was just a general example of possibility of use backward, no connection to regex quantifiers here, to be clear with it.